# How do i choose where i output in a csv file

Tags: c++

I know the title is a bit confusing, so i will try my best to explain it here.

When outputting to an excel file you can move the output location down by outputting a `"\n"` or by using `std::endl;`

is there something similar to move up?

to make it easier to understand i have some code:

```
std::ofstream outFile;
outFile.open( "outfile.csv" );
outFile << "test \n";
outFile << "test2" << "," << "test3";
```

in this case the "test" text is found ( in the excel file ) at A1, the test2 is found at A2, after that i can move it right, test3 is located at B2.

the question is: is there a way to move the next output up and left ( in this case, how can i move the next output to e.g. A1 )

a way to reset the position would work too.

Comment: No. It's a text file. You can't insert into a text file. You can overwrite or append. That means if you want to insert in the middle of a text file you have to rewrite everything after that position.

Comment: Nit pick: An Excel file is not a CSV file. CSV stands for comma seperated values and is widely used. Excel files have the extensions xml or similar. I don't know if it's possible to achieve this in an Excel file but it's not possible in an CSV file.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Moving the position in a file is possible, but it won't help you much, because your entries are all of different length. Text files are just a bunch of characters, there is no `A1` or `B2` in the text file.

Instead of working on the text file directly, if feasible, you should load all the contents into a data structure that allows you to modify specifc entries given an index.

You could use a 2d array or a `std::map<char,std::vector<std::string>> data`, so you can access an element at `A1` via `data['A'][1]`.